# Solve $x^{15} \equiv 7$ (mod $19$)

Tags: number-theory

Using the brute force approach, I found that $5$, $16$ and $17$ satisfied the congruence. How to find all possible solutions?

Comment: Consider $2$ as the primitive root modulo $19$. You would have $15\operatorname{ind} x\equiv \operatorname{ind} 7\pmod{18}$. We can easily get $\operatorname{ind} 7=6$. Therefore you are looking for the solutions to $3y\equiv -6\pmod{18}$. This gives you $\operatorname{ind} x\equiv 4, 10, 16$, meaning $x=2^4,2^{10}\equiv 17, 2^{16}\equiv5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us use Fermat's little theorem.  Since $x^{18}\equiv 1 \pmod{19}$ for any $x\not \equiv 0 \pmod{19}$, we can rewrite the equation as $x^{-3}\equiv 7\pmod{19}$, and since $7^{-1}\equiv 11\pmod{19}$, the problem is equivalent to solving

$$ x^{3}\equiv 11 \pmod{19}$$

Since this is a 3rd degree polynomial equation an $19$ is prime, there are at most $3$ solutions, all of which have been found.

However, if you only had one solution, here is a way you could generate the others.  Suppose that $\omega^{3}\equiv 1 \pmod{19}$.  If $x^{3}\equiv 11$, then $(\omega x)^{3}\equiv \omega^{3}x^{3}\equiv x^{3}\equiv 11$, and similarly with $\omega^2 x$.  Therefore, if you have one solution, finding such an $\omega$ will give you the rest.

But how do you find such an $\omega$? If you have a generator $g$, then set $\omega=g^{18/3}=g^6$.  If you don't have a generator, but you do have $h$ such that $h\neq 0, h^2\neq 1$, then either $h^6=1$, in which case we can take $\omega = h^2$, or else we can take $\omega=h^6$.